# is it necessary to mention the fields we want to perform intersection on between 2 tables?

Tags: sql, relational-database

is it? to mention the actual name of the fields you want to perform the intersection on..?
im confused...

Comment: Depends on if the tables have same/compatible columns or not, or what you want to actually do...

Comment: this is a question that someone asked me and he told me the answer is yes/no .... :/ @jarlh

Comment: As a best practice, yes :)

Comment: So the question is whether `select * from a intersect select * from b`is okay?

Answer (score 0):

Set operations (union, intersection, complement) require that their arguments be union-compatible.  That basically means they must have the same columns.  You can work with entire tables or views, in which case you don't have to specify the columns, or you can select a subset of columns, as long as both arguments to the set operation have the same columns.